# the Element in xml always has null value

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7

i want to read the xml file that i write it here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ReyPatch>

  <Key name="{8880-089B7A97D4B7}" new="true">
    <Value name="" type="string" patchedValue="5lpha" />
    <Value name="LayID" type="dword" patchedValue="2" />
    <Value name="Usons" type="dword" patchedValue="1" />
    <Value name="IsBaition" type="dword" patchedValue="0" />
    <Value key="key" name="Type" type="dword" patchedValue="2036" />
<Value key="KeyHars" name="Count" type="dword" patchedValue="0" />
  </Key>
<Key name="BBBE-A957C7628109}" new="true">
    <Value name="" type="string" patchedValue="4pha" />
    <Value name="LayD" type="dword" patchedValue="2" />
    <Value name="Utons" type="dword" patchedValue="1" />
    <Value name="IsBfinition" type="dword" patchedValue="0" />
    <Value key="Keys\0" name="Type" type="dword" patchedValue="2807" />
    <Value key="Keys\0" name="Text" type="string" patchedValue="2" />
    <Value key="Keys\1" name="Type" type="dword" patchedValue="2097" />
    <Value key="Keers" name="Count" type="dword" patchedValue="0" />
  </Key>
</ReyPatch>
```

i wrote this code but always has NullReferenceException

```
Uri url = new Uri("p.xml", UriKind.Relative);
            StreamResourceInfo resourceStream = Application.GetResourceStream(url);
            var doc = XDocument.Load(resourceStream.Stream);
            var newCookies = doc
            .Descendants()
            .Select(e =>
                new Key
                {
                    name = e.Element("name").ToString(),
                   IsNew =Convert.ToBoolean( e.Element("new").Value),
                    v = e.
                    Elements("Value").Select(i =>

                        new Value
                        {
                            name = i.Element("name").Value,
                            type = i.Element("type").Value,
                            patchedValue = i.Element("patchedValue").Value
                        }).ToArray()
                }).ToArray();
        }
```

i test all of way and i don't found any way to do it
how can i fix this?

Comment: You're looking for Elements that do not exist.  You should be looking at the Attributes instead.

Answer (score 1):

`name`, `new`, `type` and `patchedValue` are attributes, not elements. You need to use the `Attribute` method instead of `Element`. And to prevent a `NullReferenceException` when that attribute is missing, you should just cast the attribute to a `string` instead of using `ToString` or `Value`.:

```
        .Select(e =>
            new Key
            {
                name = (string)e.Attribute("name"),
               IsNew =Convert.ToBoolean((string)e.Attribute("new")),
                v = e.
                Elements("Value").Select(i =>

                    new Value
                    {
                        name = (string)i.Attribute("name"),
                        type = (string)i.Attribute("type"),
                        patchedValue = (string)i.Attribute("patchedValue")
                    }).ToArray()
            }).ToArray();
```

Comment: half of that work but no all
when i comment 
 name = e.Attribute("name").ToString(),
 IsNew =Convert.ToBoolean( e.Attribute("new").Value),
all thing work but when i un comment that again i have  NullReferenceException :(

Answer (score 0):

You are getting exception because you are getting all descendants of your xml. You should use `.Descendants("Key")`. Otherwise first element that will be selected is `<ReyPatch>` element, which do not have element `<name>` and you get exception on `e.Element("name").ToString()`.

@juharr is correct, you are trying to get elements instead of attributes. See difference [XML Elements vs. Attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/dtd_el_vs_attr.asp)

Whole parsing should look like (I strongly recommend to use casting of nodes instead of getting their values):

```
 doc.Descendants("Key")
    .Select(key => new Key()
    {
        name = (string)key.Attribute("name"),
        IsNew = (bool)key.Attribute("new"),
        v = key.Elements()
                .Select(value => new Value()
                {
                    name = (string)value.Attribute("name"),
                    type = (string)value.Attribute("type"),
                    patchedValue = (string)value.Attribute("patchedValue")
                }).ToArray()
    }).ToArray();
```

And I suggest you to use PascalCase for properties naming, and more descriptive properties. E.g.

```
public class Key
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public bool IsNew { get; set; }
   public Value[] Values { get; set; }
}
```